# $3$-subsets $S$ of a set $\{2,3,..,50,53,55\}$ which satisfy the given condition

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find number of all $3$-subsets $S$ of a set $\{2,3,..,50,53,55\}$ which satisfy the given condition:

For every $x,y$ $\in S, (x\neq y, |x-y|>2)$

I solved it this way:

Let $A$ be the family of all $3$-subsets $S$ of a set $\{2,3,..,50,53,55\}$ which satisfy the given condition. Present $A$ as a union of sets $A_{1}, A_{2}, A_{3}$ defined as:

$A_{1}=\{S\in A|53\in S, 55\notin S\}$ (I can't have $53$ and $55$ in the same set since their difference is $2$, and it has to be at least $3$)

$A_{2}=\{S\in A|53\notin S, 55\in S\}$

$A_{3}=\{S\in A|53\notin S, 55\notin S\}$

By the sum principle it will be: $|A|= |A_{1}|+|A_{2}|+|A_{3}|$

Now, I know that these are wrong:

$|A_{1}|=f_{2}(50,2)$

$|A_{2}|=f_{2}(50,2)$

$|A_{3}|=f_{2}(49,3)$

Here are my qiestions:

For $|A_{1}|$, $53$ is definitely in a $3$-subset, but other elements are from $2$ to $50$, I wrote $n=50$ in formula but that is not correct, it would mean that $1$ is a part of a given set, so how to fix that? Similar problems for $|A_{2}|$ and $|A_{3}|$...

Formula I used: Number of $k$-subsets $S$ of $[n]=\{1,..,n\}$ such that for every $x,y\in S, |x-y|>v$ is $f_{v}(n,k)=\binom{n-(k-1)v}{k}$. Also, $k,n,v\geq 0, n\geq (k-1)v$.

Comment: What are the precise elements of $\{2,3,\ldots, 50, 53, 55\}$?

Comment: $\{2,3,...,50\} \cup \{53\} \cup \{55\}$

Comment: Oh, so $\{\,x\in\Bbb Z\mid 2\le x\le 50\,\}\cup\{53,55\}$? (Unfortunately, "$\ldots$" has a habit of being ambigous)

Comment: yes, that is it.. sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

If we ignore $53$ and $55$, we deal with a set of $49$ consecutive integers.
Let $f(n)$ be the number of sets with the given distance condition that are subsets of a given set of $n$ consecutive numbers. Then for $n$ big enough, such a set either contains the largest available number and apart from that is one of $f(n-3)$ sets that avoid the top three numbers, or it does not contain the largest number and hence is one of $f(n-1)$ sets that avoid the largest number.
In other words, we have a recursion
$$ f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-3)$$
with initial conditions
$$ f(0)=1, f(1)=2, f(2)=3.$$
Use this to compute $f(49)$ and (as we independently have three options for the membership of $53, 55$) multiply by $3$.

Comment: Since I am studying discrete mathematics at a University, I am not allowed yet to use recursions, because we haven't studied them yet.. is there possibly other way of solving? Thank You for answering...